# After reboot a lot of processes ran in the isolated cpus

Tags: kernel, cpu

**This question is migrated from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75641975/ubuntu-after-booting-a-lot-processes-run-n-isolated-cpus) since it was marked as off-topic there**

I am running `ubuntu 22.04` with kernel `vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic`. I isolated a few cpus by editing `/etc/default/grub` and did a `sudo update-grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=4-7"
```

However, after I rebooted the system, I saw a lot of processes already running on one of the isolated CPUs, including some `dockerd` and `systemd` processes.

(I have rebooted for several times and observe the same)

I also checked `/proc/cmdlin` and `dmesg`. It does show that `isolcpus` is in the command line.

Is there a bug?

PS:

1. I also found some one saying [similar](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/132433-docker-still-scheduling-on-isolated-cpu-coresthreads/), but don't know whether they are related.
2. There is a page on [how to isolate cpus](https://docs.mirantis.com/mosk/latest/deploy/deploy-openstack/advanced-config/advanced-compute/configure-cpu-isolation.html). when discussing the approach using `isolcpus`, it still asks to use `cset` to ping the docker and kubepods to the unshielded cpus. Does this mean that `docker` will generally not respect the `isolcpus` settings?

Answer (score 1):

Isolcpus did not work as I was expecting. [I found an answer here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282256/isolcpus-kernel-parameter-has-no-effect-on-ubuntu-16-04-desktop) The two key points from that thread are:

> It appears that presently, isolcpus= only affects user space threads,
> and hence, kernel threads will show up on the isolated CPU's.
>
> In summary, Ubuntu isn't ignoring the option, it's working as
> intended. Whether it's working as desired is a different query.

Comment: For me, not only the kworkers, but the user apps are running in the isolated CPUS. If the user session leader is running there, all the children will be started over there and have no chance to be rescheduled to other threads.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1297258)

Comment: @TaylorR You are correct. I intended it as more of a comment, but I didn't see a comment link when I wrote it. I edited it to try and make it as much of an answer as I can.

Comment: @doraemon I've given up on using isolcpus to try and keep one CPU clear for my real time process. I'm looking into cset now and can let you know how that works out.